# Togglefield in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a togglefield in sencha as below

```
{
    xtype: 'togglefield',
    name: 'pushnotifications',
    id: 'pushnotifications',                                   
    label: 'Enable Push Notifications?',
    labelWidth: '40%',
    height: '100%',
    listeners: {                           
        change: function(field, thumb, enabled) {
            alert('sss');
        } 
    }                          
}
```

The problem is that the event 'change' works only when the toggle button is dragged and not when it is changed by clicking.
How can I get the listener working even when clicking?Is there any other event that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely related to the `id` field.  If views are not destroyed correctly and you end up with multiples of the same ID in the DOM then the event wiring can go wonky.

If you've used the `id` for a ref in the controller then try using the `xtype` instead.

Comment: i commented id, still no change. Also , the same code is working fine on sencha fiddle http://www.senchafiddle.com/#A2hhq